# Divisibility question while enumerating endomorphisms: PART 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

From *endomorphisms of rank 1* of the full transformation semigroup $[n]^{[n]}$ or *idempotents* in $[n]^{[n]}$, we have
$$c_n:=\sum_{m=1}^n\binom{n}mm^{n-m}.$$

> **QUESTION.** Is it true that $n$ divides  $c_n - 1$?

Comment: Yes, it is. See Exercise 1 **(c)** in [my UMN Fall 2017 Math 4990 homework set #6](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/t/17f/hw6os.pdf). The proof is a simple application of the absorption formula $m \dbinom{n}{m} = n \dbinom{n-1}{m-1}$. If I am not mistaken, it is easy to make this a bijective proof.